# is there a way to use an if statement in the WHERE part of the SQL query?

Tags: sql

Is there a way to use an if statement in the where part of the SQL query? 
For example:

```
 SELECT count(*) 
    from table_name tb 
    where ( if (@enddate>dateadd("d",2,@date) then date > tb.date 
    else dateadd("d",2,@date)>tb.date) )
```

I need to somehow do this check where I check if the date 2 days later is not greater than the end date, otherwise I have to use the end date by default.

Comment: You can use a CASE expression!

Comment: This really should have a tag for the SQL engine being used.

Comment: What database are you using here - MySQL?

Answer (score 4):

You can use CASE expression:

```
SELECT count(*) 
FROM table_name tb 
WHERE (CASE WHEN (@enddate>dateadd("d",2,@date)) THEN date > tb.date 
       ELSE
          dateadd("d",2,@date)>tb.date
       END);
```

Comment: I did write this, but it comes out with "Incorrect syntax near '>'." !! I have checked 3 times for the brackets, punctuation, variables, and variable types it's all ok.. I think I am going crazy...!

Comment: That's what I am using and it comes up with the error I mentioned above... :(

Comment: No, I have made a little change after you told that you are getting the error. So, pls, copy it and try again.

Comment: **I found IT!!!**

  
SELECT count(*) 
FROM table tb 
WHERE (CASE WHEN (@enddate>dateadd("d",2,@date)) 
THEN @date
       ELSE
          dateadd("d",2,@date)
       END)>tb.date);

Comment: Well, the only difference from what I posted is that you use @date instead of date in the condition WHEN (@enddate>dateadd("d",2,@date)) THEN, which was wrong in your initial post. Anyway I am glad that it worked for you!

Answer (score 1):

this answer is tailored onto to the case explained into the question as the issue to solve and not on the title.

to handle that case there is no need for a special solution and/or keyword, it is handled nicely using a regular `WHERE` clause:

```
 SELECT count(*) 
 from table_name tb 
 where (@enddate > dateadd("d",2,@date) AND date > tb.date)
       OR
       (dateadd("d",2,@date) > tb.date))
```

Comment: I agree; this is more elegant than the case statement.

Answer (score 0):

I found the following:

```
CASE
 WHEN (DATENAME(dw,@st) = 'Monday')
       AND (
        ((Day(@st) = 01))
        OR ((Day(@st) = 02))
        OR ((Day(@st) = 03))
       )
  THEN DATEADD(DAY,-2,@st) 
 ELSE DATEADD(DAY, - 1, DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, 0, GETDATE()), 0))
END
```

And it actually works quite nicely.

This will only run when the first working day of the month is a Monday, hence that's when I want to get the weekend's data. Otherwise, I already have it.